# The Celtic word "al" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, borrowing

I found a strange word while I read my Latin–Portuguese dictionary (Dicionário latino-português por F. R. Dos Santos Saraiva). The word is "al". The dictionary says that it's a Celtic word used by Vergilius and its meaning is unknown. I tried to find it in OLD and Gaffiot, and there was nothing. (I never read Vergilius.) Is this word real?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Joonas says, this word is a hapax legomenon (word that only appears once). The only attestation listed in the TLL comes from Ausonius, a fourth-century poet; in his *Technopaegnion*, every line ends with a different monosyllable, which leads to using a lot of obscure words.

The specific quote comes from the section titled *Grammaticomastix* ("Scourge of Grammarians"), which uses a lot of obscure monosyllables found in poetry:

> die, quid significent Catalepta Maronis? in his *al*
> Celtarum posuit; sequitur non lucidius *tau*
> *So what do Vergil's "Catalepta" mean? In these, he's placed*
> *Celtic "al"; he follows it up, no more clearly, with "tau".*

The problem is, this "Celtic *al*" doesn't actually appear in the *Catalepta*. Vergil does mention a *tau Gallicum* at one point—probably meaning a letter Ꟈ that appears in Gaulish inscriptions—but no *al*. Which means Ausonius's copy of the *Catalepta* may be different from the versions that have survived to the present, or there might be an error in transmission from Ausonius.

Either way, it certainly does not seem to have been used as a word in Latin.

P.S. The passage in the *Catalepta* talks about a rhetorician brewing up a nasty concoction of Gaulish *tau* and *min* and *sphin*; the latter two are archaic Greek pronouns that were mostly of interest to grammarians. Based on this, the Loeb quotes one commentary that thinks these words were chosen as puns: Latin-speakers in Gaul might have shortened *taurum* to *tau*, for example, and then *al* could have been a local abbreviation for *allium*. As far as I can tell there's no actual evidence for this (it's pure speculation), and the fact that *al* doesn't appear in surviving versions of the *Catalepta* is a problem for the theory.

Answer (score 9):

As cmw points out in a comment, you can access [TLL (Thesaurus Linguae Latinae)](https://thesaurus.badw.de/tll-digital/tll-open-access.html) online, and here's the entry for *al*:

[image: TLL entry]

This seems to be word that occurs only once (a *hapax legomenon*), and the entry suggests that it may well be a copying error.
And even if it was really in the original text, I still wouldn't count it as a Latin word as it is a quote from another language within a Latin text.

Most dictionaries will not include words like this, but TLL is very comprehensive and your best guess with very rare words.

So, simply put, no, this word is not real.

Comment: Today I learned hapax legomenon (a word that only appears once). I can't help but ask if there is a elegant way of saying "a word that is not real."

Comment: @Wastrel Whether there is a scholarly term for unreal words similar to *hapax legomenon* would make a nice question for the site. Just bear in mind that there can be many ways to be not real and in many cases there there is no reason to speak of such words. A word worth looking into and comparing to is "unattested", as it gets pretty close.

Comment: @Wastrel "Ghost word" is sometimes used for this.

Comment: @TKR Thank you. The wikipedia article for "ghost word" has several amusing examples of words being invented accidentally, by typographical error or a mistaken translation, and then being published in dictionaries.