# Is there a Latin parallel to the TLG website?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, koine-greek

The TLG (=Thesaurus Linguae Graecae) is an incredibly helpful tool for understanding how an author uses a certain word. For example, if I wanted to learn how the word ἀνάπαυσις was used by Clement of Alexandria, I could start by doing a TLG search for all occurrences of this word in the Koine corpus. This would give me a sense of how the word was used around the time Clement was writing.

**Is there something analogous to the TLG for Latin?**

(For those who are curious what my current research questions is...Right now I am interested in the meaning of the phrase

*die dominicae resurrectionis*

as used by Tertullian. Can this phrase refer to any Sunday, or does it only refer to Easter Sunday?)

Comment: Yes. Someone showed the Thesaurus linguae latinae.  See An answer in my question about a celtic word in latin.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças Manuel's question can be found https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19528/the-celtic-word-al-in-latin   and the TLL can be found here: https://thesaurus.badw.de/tll-digital/tll-open-access.html Manuel's comment would make a great answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not an exact equivalent, as far as I'm aware. The TLG is a real treasure and Latin would definitely benefit from a sister site.

The closest thing is probably [PHI Latin Texts](https://latin.packhum.org/), which has a comprehensive database of Latin literary texts, with the big exception of Christian texts. They also stop earlier than the TLG does. Still, it's a searchable database and uses good quality editions, too.

For Tertullian, though, you'll have to go elsewhere. My suggestion for searching Christian texts is using the "site" function on Google, so [`site:thelatinlibrary.com "tertullian" "die dominico"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Athelatinlibrary.com+tertullian+%22die+dominico%22).

What's really missing with both of these ways is that they you cannot search by lexeme. You'll have to know all the forms of a word yourself and search that way.

Despite the similar name, the [Thesaurus Linguae Latinae](https://thesaurus.badw.de/tll-digital/tll-open-access.html) is not the same as the TLG. Rather, it's a comprehensive *dictionary* of Latin words. And it's not finished yet, so you can't look up information about *resurrectio*. But you're in luck! They do reference Tertullian under the *dominicus* headword, so if you download that PDF you can find the citations. They seem to indicate that it's used to refer to Sunday (as does Lewis and Short), but you can check it out for yourself.

So you can often get what you need with TLL + PHI (or searching TheLatinLibrary), but unfortunately, you'll have to work at it a bit more than you would need to with the TLG.

Comment: And then there’s also Bibliotheca Teubneriana Latina Online (institutional subscription only)

Comment: @AlexB. Ah, I no longer have any institutional access, so I can't check it out. Does it replicate the TLG experience, or is it more like PHI?

Comment: It is rather limited in what you can do there now, take a look at the search options https://www.degruyter.com/database/btl/html?lang=en (at the very top) But it’s a step in the right direction, I hope one day we’ll get something similar to TLG for Latin